# how to translate custom language to html

Tags: python, parsing

I'm trying to do a conversion of a custom language to `html`.
The following example should be intuitive-easy enough to understand without explaining:
This input file...

```
css:
    define(style):
        if default:
            background-color=black
        if hovered:
            background-color=blue
    apply(style, tag=h1, tag=h2)

html:
    body(id="hello"):
        paragraph(id=demo):
            "This is a paragraph.
        input(type="button", onclick="displayDate()"):
            "Display Date

js:
    def displayDate():
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=Date()
```

...should be translated to...

```
h1 {
    background-color: black
}
h1 :hover {
    background-color: blue
}
id {
    background-color=black
}
id :hover {
    background-color=blue
}

<html>
    <body id="hello">
        <p id="demo">This is a paragraph.</p>
        <input type="button", onclick="displayDate()">Display Date</button>
    </body>

    <script>
        function displayDate() {
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=Date()
        }
    </script>
</html>
```

The input file has the following rules:

- It has the same indent-based syntax as Python, so there should be
  indent checking.
- Lines starting in quotation marks are interpreted as content.
- Certain statements should exist only in certain context, for example, the define statement
  should only exist inside a css block.

I've been writing my parser using Regex, but halfway realised that Regex is slow, and may not be adequate since the generation of the HTML should be quick, which is not one of Regex strengths.

Googling/surfing brings `pyparsing`, `PLY`, `ANTLR` to my eyes, but I don't really know/understand what they do and whether should I use them.

Which path should I follow?

Comment: Why not use a template engine such as Jinja?

Comment: Regular expressions are not particularly slow and you're going to be using them under the hood in any parser. pyparsing is pretty easy to work with, assuming you already have your grammar in BNF.

Comment: Take a look at http://haml.info/ which is very similar.

Comment: Pyparsing struggles with indent-based languages - it *can* be done, but it takes some extra work.

Comment: @Cfreak I'm creating something like Jinja because I don't like their syntax. They regard it as beautiful, but I fully disagree.

Comment: @PaulMcGuire Wow, word from pyparsing author himself. I love you StackOverflow.

Comment: If using regex is slow, the solution might be as simple as pre-compiling your patterns (see re.compile).